# Click event being called twice after upgrading to Angular 1.2.5 and ngTouch?

Tags: angularjs

I just upgraded my mobile phonegap app to Angular 1.2.5 from 1.1.5 and also replaced my hammer.js with the angular-touch (ngTouch) module and every click event now gets fired twice... once for the standard ng-click in Angular and a second time for the ngTouch ng-click event. Anyone else seeing this issue? Any ideas on how to fix/debug? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your example at http://plnkr.co/?